# Kubernetes API server

Tags: python, kubernetes

So I have just started using Kubernetes API server and I tried this example :

```
from kubernetes import client, config
def main():
    # Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper
    # utility. If no argument provided, the config will be loaded from
    # default location.
    config.load_kube_config()

    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
    ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
    for i in ret.items:
        print("%s\t%s\t%s" %
              (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This worked but it returned the pods that are on my local minikube, I want to get the pods that are at the kubernetes server here :
`http://192.168.237.115:8080`
How do I do that?

When I do `kubectl config view` , I get this :

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/piyush/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.99.100:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/piyush/.minikube/apiserver.crt
    client-key: /home/piyush/.minikube/apiserver.key
```

I know this is for the local cluster I set up. I want to know how to modify this to make api requests to kubernetes server  on `http://192.168.237.115:8080`

Answer (score 8):

You can actually create a simple api wrapper. This way you can pass through different yaml configuration files, that I imagine may have different hosts

```
import yaml

from kubernetes import client
from kubernetes.client import Configuration
from kubernetes.config import kube_config


class K8s(object):
    def __init__(self, configuration_yaml):
        self.configuration_yaml = configuration_yaml
        self._configuration_yaml = None

    @property
    def config(self):
        with open(self.configuration_yaml, 'r') as f:
            if self._configuration_yaml is None:
                self._configuration_yaml = yaml.load(f)
        return self._configuration_yaml

    @property
    def client(self):
        k8_loader = kube_config.KubeConfigLoader(self.config)
        call_config = type.__call__(Configuration)
        k8_loader.load_and_set(call_config)
        Configuration.set_default(call_config)
        return client.CoreV1Api()


# Instantiate your kubernetes class and pass in config
kube_one = K8s(configuration_yaml='~/.kube/config1')
kube_one.client.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)

kube_two = K8s(configuration_yaml='~/.kube/config2')
kube_two.client.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
```

Also another neat reference in libcloud. https://github.com/apache/libcloud/blob/trunk/libcloud/container/drivers/kubernetes.py.

Good luck! Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 6):

I have two solution for you:

1. [prefered] Configure your kubectl (i.e. ~/.kube/config) file. After kubectl works with your cluster, python client should automatically work with `load_kube_config`. See here for configuring kubectl: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/share-configuration/
2. You can configure python client directly. For a complete list of configurations, look at: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/blob/8704ce39c241f3f184d01833dcbaf1d1fb14a2dc/configuration.py#L48

You may need to set some of those configuration for your client to connect to your cluster. For example, if you don't have any certificate or SSL enabled:

```
from kubernetes import client, configuration
def main():
    configuration.host = "http://192.168.237.115:8080"
    configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = "Bearer"
    configuration..api_key['authorization'] = "YOUR_TOKEN"
    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    ...
```

You may need to set other configurations such as username, api_key, etc. That's why I think if you follow first solution it would be easier.

Answer (score 3):

`config.load_kube_config()` takes `context` as a parameter. If passed `None` (the default) then the current context will be used. Your current context is probably your minikube.

See here:
https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/blob/436351b027df2673869ee00e0ff5589e6b3e2b7d/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py#L283

`config.load_kube_config(context='some context')`

If you are not familiar with Kubernetes contexts, 
Kubernetes stores your configuration under `~/.kube/config` (default location). In it you will find context definition for every cluster you may have access to. A field called `current-context` defines your current context.

You can issue the following commands:

`kubectl config current-context` to see the current context

`kubectl config view` to view all the configuration

Comment: When nothing is passed to `config.load_kube_config()` my Jupyter notebook actually referred the current context which was set from PowerShell.  Hence like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72125590/1176573) we can use as you mentioned: `config.load_kube_config(context='some context')`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me the file `~/.kube/config`

If you update the API server in it, the python module `kubernetes` will automatically pick up the new API server you nominated.

```
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: [Update real ca.crt here]
    server: http://192.168.237.115:8080
```

There are other changes in `~/.kube/config` as well, you'd better get the config from the remote kubernetes server directly.

After successfully config with remote kubernetes API servers, you should be fine to run kubectl and get the deployments, deamons, etc.

Then you should be fine to run with python kubernetes SDK

Comment: So this is what I get when I do `kubectl config view `:                          `apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/piyush/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.99.100:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/piyush/.minikube/apiserver.crt
    client-key: /home/piyush/.minikube/apiserver.key `

Comment: I know I have to modify this to add cluster. But what values do I give to certificate authority?

Comment: Can you update the config file in your original question first?

Comment: Who is the kubernetes admin, you can ask for it. Normally the config file is under `/etc/kuberentes` in kubernete server. Dig it by yourself.

Comment: Okay, I understand I have to pass the kube config file. This for the server  `apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: local
  cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
    server: http://127.0.0.1:8080
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/node-node1.pem
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/node-node1-key.pem
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: local
    user: kubelet
  name: kubelet-cluster.local
current-context: kubelet-cluster.local` Can I directly use this by changing only the server address.

Comment: Replace the server from  `http://127.0.0.1:8080` to `http://192.168.237.115:8080`. you need to copy the pem key to local (I am not sure this part, I currently don't have the environment to check)