# What does it mean "kubectl config set-cluster" what does it actually does?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

While using this command for RBAC `"kubectl config set-cluster test --server=https://127.0.0.1:52807"`  the IP here is from the kind-cluster that I am running after which I use `"kubectl config set-context test --cluster=test"` followed by required credentials & switch to the context by `"kubectl config use-context test"` and I am in the test context but with the first command  I am configuring the config file I got that but m I making a cluster within a cluster what you guys understand please help me clear my doubt what is it actually doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`kubectl config set-cluster` sets a cluster entry in your `kubeconfig` file (usually found in `$HOME/.kube/config`). The `kubeconfig` file defines how your `kubectl` is configured.

The cluster entry defines where `kubectl` can find the kubernetes cluster to talk to. You can have multiple clusters defined in your `kubeconfig` file.

`kubectl config set-context` sets a context element, which is used to combine a cluster, namespace and user into a single element so that `kubectl` has everything it needs to communicate with the cluster. You can have multiple contexts, for example one per kubernetes cluster that you're managing.

`kubectl config use-context` sets your current context to be used in `kubectl`.

So to walk through your commands:

- `kubectl config set-cluster test --server=https://127.0.0.1:52807` creates a new entry in `kubeconfig` under the `clusters` section with a cluster called `test` pointing towards `https://127.0.0.1:52807`
- `kubectl config set-context test --cluster=test` creates a new context in `kubeconfig` called `test` and tells that context to point to a cluster called `test`
- `kubectl config use-context test` changes the the current context in `kubeconfig` to a context called `test` (which you just created).

More docs on `kubectl config` and `kubeconfig`:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration

Comment: Could this answer be any more beautiful?